# Prove that the sum of the altitudes of a triangle is $\leq 3(R+r)$

Tags: geometry

Prove that the sum of the altitudes of a triangle is $\leq 3(R+r)$

I couldn't solve this but I think the equation $R+r = R \left( \displaystyle\sum_{A,B,C} \cos A \right)$ might help.

I'm looking for a synthetic (pure geometric) solution however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until we get a synthetic solution, I'll mention this. One altitude is $$a\sin B=2R\sin A\sin B=R(\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B))=R(\cos(A-B)+\cos C).$$So you want to prove $\cos(A-B)+\cdots\le 2(\cos A+\cdots)$. It suffices to note$$\cos A+\cos B-\cos(A-B)\\=\cos A+\cos B-\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B\\=1-(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)-\sin A\sin B\\=1-4\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}\\\ge1-4\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}>0.$$